# Variable inside a jquery background change

Tags: jquery

I'm having troubles with the syntax for a simple line of jquery, I cant seem to insert the 'this.src' part correctly, I get muddled up with quotes and commas etc. Heres what I currently have :

```
$('#blog-hover-image').css("background-image", "url(", this.src, ")");
```

How do I insert the this.src part correctly please ?

I have a url stored in this.src from earlier in the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
$('#blog-hover-image').css("background-image", "url(\"" + this.src + "\")");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @ScottHunter -  mark as the answer if solved what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

You were close but you need to use the `+` for string concatenation, not the `,`.

```
$('#blog-hover-image').css("background-image", "url('" + this.src + "')");
```